# Bootstrap sticky footer is not sticky

Tags: html, css

Trying to add the typical bootstrap sticky footer - but cannot get it to work. I've been through it loads of times and suspect I am making some kind of stupid mistake - but I can't find it. I've done loads of searching on stackoverflow and been unable to make the numerous solutions work and I don't know why. I think I've got everything in the wrapper, and I've got the 'push' div too - but it's still refusing to work.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
    <link href="Calums2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="footerspecs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="navbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class = "navbarandwideimage"><!-- HERE STARTS IMAGE AND NAVBAR -->
            <div style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/3w90pjv.jpg); position:absolute; left: 0%; width:100%; top:7%; bottom: 7%;">
                <div class = "turnips2" style="position:absolute; bottom:15%; left:5%; right:70%; color=white;">This summer, five adventurers from Inverness and one Northern Irishman completed the first unsupported hike across Iceland from the south to the north - a distance of 400 miles across <b>Europe's last wilderness.</b>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar"
            <div class="list" style="Position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-nav">
                                <li><a href="Home.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>
                                <li><a href="team.html"><h2>Team</h2></a></li>
                                <li><a href="kyrgyzstan.html"><h2>Kyrgyzstan</h2></a></li>
                                <li><a href="Blog.html"><h2>Blog</h2></a></li>
                                <li><a href="Expeditions.html"><h2>Expeditions</h2></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
                </nav>
            </div>
            <style>
                text-align:justify;
            </style>
            </div>       <!-- HERE ENDSIMAGE AND NAVBAR -->
            <!-- HERE STARTS MAIN BODY - PUT YOUR WORK HERE MAGS (in mainbody div)-->
            <div class="mainbody" style="position: absolute; top:100%;" > 
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h3> Krygyzstan - the land of horses </h3>
                    <p> lots <br> of <br> text <br> here </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="push">
            </div>  
        </div><!-- HERE ENDS MAIN BODY -->
        <div class="footer"> <!-- FOOTER GOES HERE -->
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="socialmedia">
                        <a target="_blank" title="follow me on instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com/PLACEHOLDER">
                            <img alt="follow me on instagra" src="https://5a5a57ff32a328601212-ee0df397c56b146e91fe14be42fa361d.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon/logos_glyph/Oxi2BIzyfeN5INYU7lta/Glyph_Logo_thumbnail200.png" style=" width:3%; height:3%; border=50px;">
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-muted">Place sticky footer content here.</p>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div> <!-- HERE ENDS FOOTER -->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS for footer:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.socialmedia {
    border-style:solid;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
    /*height:100%;*/   /*you need to comment this height*/
    margin:0 auto;
    min-height:100%;
    padding-bottom:-30px;
    width:985px;
    position: relative;  /*and you need to add this */
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

REST OF CSS:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  float: none;
}
.navbar-default {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-width: 0px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(150, 155, 155, );
}
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
ul.nav li a>h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-brand {
    padding-top:4px !important; 
    padding-bottom:0 !important;
    height: 28px;
}
.navbar {
     min-height:28px !important;
 }
.navbar button {
    position:absolute; 
    left:50px; 
    top:0px; 
    border-style:none; 
    border-radius:0px;
}
.list {
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
.synopsis {
      color:white;
      text-align: center;
}
.teampics .row {
    margin-top: 17%;
    text-align:center;
}
h3 {
    text-align:center;
}
.turnips2 {
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 2.3ex;
    text-align:justify;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Indentation is important. You have an unfinished opening tag and at least two incorrect/extra closing tags.

Comment: @tylerH Thank you - I am going to go through it and try to find these, and also get beautify for brackets to hopefully improve the indentation

Comment: you can use a service like http://jsfiddle.net to paste your code into a sandbox, and then click the "tidy" button to automatically handle code indentation for you

Comment: this sounds excellent - will immediately get on this

Comment: @tylerH  Thanks for the advice - I tidied it using jsfiddle - does it strip out unfinished tags as well?  Can't seem to see any and running the tidied code gets me the same output as I was getting previously - i.e footer in wrong place.  Thank you for helping me

Comment: No, it shouldn't; it should highlight them in red. I've rolled back your edit because it seems to re-add a bunch of the superfluous spaces I removed when I manually indented the code.

Comment: @tylerh - I ran it (your indented one) through jsfiddle - I found the unfinished tag (<<div class="navbar" )and closed it - but I don't see how I have extra closing tags - yes jsfiddle says I have several errors, but these seem to be due to <head> not being neccessary in jsfiddle, and also says a couple of my div close tags are red - but they link up with opening tags, in brackets at least...

Comment: You have one instance where you close a `<div>` tag inside of an `<a>` without ever opening the `<div>` in the first place.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fishy12345/00fo81hf/ - uploaded it all, it looks approximately the same but not identical to how it appears on chrome for me - can clearly see how the footer is not at the bottom - has text underneath it.  thank you for your continuing help

Comment: @tylerh - sorry, got that just after posting my prev comment.  I've rearranged the jsfiddle so that it's now not giving errors - I think it's successfully published.  however, the footer is still not sticky.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/00fo81hf/2/ - the corrected fiddle - with no unclosed tags that I can detect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  /*Your other styles go here...*/
}
```

Comment: This gives a fixed footer - not a sticky one

Comment: unless I have misunderstood it entirely - (very possible) - this is what I thought a sticky footer was - http://cbracco.me/css-sticky-footer-effect/ i.e not constantly visible on screen, but always at v bottom of page

Comment: @CalumNicoll That's not a sticky footer, this is a sticky footer: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/. However, for what you're wanting, you probably just need to add `min-height: 100%' to your body style

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  I tried adding min-height: 100% to the body style - but unfortunately it continues to not work